# How to check if a json nested object has empty arrays in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, How can I check if each of the **regions** below are empty or not.
In the below example, since since all 3 regions are empty, it should return true

```
"objects": [
    {
      "zone": "zone_name",
      "clusters": [
        {
          "cluster_name": "abc" ,
          "regions": []
        },
        {
          "cluster_name": "def",
          "regions": []
        },
        {
          "cluster_name": "ghi",
          "regions": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and in this example, since one of the region is not empty it should return false

```
"objects": [
        {
          "zone": "zone_name",
          "clusters": [
            {
              "cluster_name": "abc" ,
              "regions": []
            },
            {
              "cluster_name": "def",
              "regions": []
            },
            {
              "cluster_name": "ghi",
              "regions": ['UK','london']
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

How can I achieve this using sql in snowflake?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing? For example, do you not know how to query JSON data in Snowflake; Do you not know how to get all instances of an attribute when they are repeating; do you not know how to compare the values when you have selected them; etc?

Comment: Yes I'm able to get individual items from the Json like clusters[0].regions, clusters[1].regions, But I want get it as combined, something like regions = {[],[],[]} and check if all elements/array are empty, and if regions = {[],[],['UK','london]} I want to identify one of array is not empty, This is where im stuck, and I want to do this check as a where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to recursively flatten it first

```
create or replace temporary table t as 

select 1 as id, parse_json($${"objects": [
        {
          "zone": "zone_name",
          "clusters": [
            {
              "cluster_name": "abc" ,
              "regions": []
            },
            {
              "cluster_name": "def",
              "regions": []
            },
            {
              "cluster_name": "ghi",
              "regions": ['UK','london']
            }
          ]
        }
      ]}$$) as col;

 select id, case when max(value) = [] then true else false end as flag
 from t, lateral flatten(col, recursive=>true)
 where key ='regions'
 group by id;
```